# when field is valid but error message is showing and i used fluent validation and don't know how to apply client side validation to remove error msg

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

RuleFor(product => product.DamagedProductsByEaches).Equal(0).DependentRules(() => {
RuleFor(product => product.ProductDamagedTypeSelected).GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Can't be empty");
}).When(product => product.DamagedProductsByCases > 0);

```
        RuleFor(product => product.DamagedProductsByCases).Equal(0).DependentRules(() => {
            RuleFor(product => product.ProductDamagedTypeSelected).GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Can't be empty");
        }).When(product => product.DamagedProductsByEaches > 0);
```

Comment: Can you tell me what your rule want ? And can you share your controller code and view code ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

Employee Model

```
public class Employee
    { 
        public int DamagedProductsByCases { get; set;}
        public int ProductDamagedTypeSelected { get; set; }
        public  int DamagedProductsByEaches { get; set; }
    }
```

Employee_Validation

```
     public class Employee_Validation : AbstractValidator<Employee>
        {
            public Employee_Validation()
            {            
                RuleFor(x => x.DamagedProductsByCases).Equal(0).DependentRules(() => {
                    RuleFor(x => x.ProductDamagedTypeSelected).GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Can't be empty");
                }).When(product => product.DamagedProductsByEaches > 0);
    
            }
        }
```

EmployeeController

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Employee Emp)
        {
            Employee_Validation Obj = new Employee_Validation();
          var Result = Obj.Validate(Emp);

            if(!Result.IsValid)
            {
                foreach(ValidationFailure  result in Result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(result.PropertyName, result.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return View(Emp);
        }
    }
```

Index view

```
  <h1>Index</h1>
    
    <h4>Employee</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Index">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
     <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DamagedProductsByCases" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DamagedProductsByCases" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DamagedProductsByCases" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ProductDamagedTypeSelected" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="ProductDamagedTypeSelected" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ProductDamagedTypeSelected" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DamagedProductsByEaches" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DamagedProductsByEaches" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DamagedProductsByEaches" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: thankyou so much for the help #Qing Guo

Comment: Hi @smriti, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know? Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.

Comment: yeah quite helpful and also let me know if I can contact you

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't give you my contact information due to regulations, but if you have any questions, you can ask in the forum. I and others will help you when we see it. Let's learn together!